# Series limiting resistor?

Tags: diodes, power-electronics, zener, semiconductors

I have used a 3.3V and a 4.7V Zener diode.  What value series resistor do I need for them to work properly? The test current for 3.3V is 76mA and for 4.7V is 53mA.

Comment: A 3.3V zener is really not a good way to get a 3.3V power supply in almost every case, if that's what you are planning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a zener of voltage VZ fed from a Voltage source of Vin via a resistor of Rz with no other load.

Iz = V/R = (Vin-Vz)/ Rz  ... 1
Call this value of Iz Iz_max.

Zener power dissipation = Vz x Iz  ... 2
Usually zeners are rated to dissipate this power in free air - except maybe for unusual package types.

In this case you do not specify Vin so Rz can only be calculated in terms of the above parameters

Rearranging (1)
Rz = (Vin-Vz)/Iz

Vz will vary somewhat with Iz but is "close enough" to rated value for most purposes.

As you draw current for a load Iz will reduce
Iz_variable  =  Iz_max - Iload.
Regulation will stop when Iload >= Iz_max

---

Using a 9V transformer, bridge rectifier, 1000 uF capacitor.

Vdc unloaded = VAC_RMS x 1.414 ~= 12.7V
Actual loaded DC depends on transformer and load current, but probably 11 - 12 VDC.
Assume 11 VDC

For 3V3 zener with Imax = 75 mA max current.
Rz must drop 11-3.3 = 7.7V
Rz = V/I = (11-3.3)/.075 = 7.7/.075 = 103 Ohms.
Say 100 Ohms.
Power dissipation in resistor = v^2/R = (11-3.3)^2/100 = 592 mW.
Use a 1 watt resistor (at least).

Power in zener with no load =~ V x I = 3.3 x 0.075 =~ 250 mW.
Power lost in resistor is about 2.4 x power dissipated in zener!
Overall efficiency = Vz/Vin = 3.3/11 = 30%.
This is the result of using a linear regulator.
Using a linear regulator IC will NOT improve efficiency at maximum load but will reduce power dissipation at lighter loads.

For 4.7 V zener at 53 mA.
Rz = V/I = (11-4.7)/.053 = 119 Ohms.
Use 120 Ohms.
Max efficiency = Vz/Vin = 4.7/11 ~= 43%.
Resistor power dissipation = Vr^2/R = (11-4.7)^2/120 = 0.33 watt.
Use 1/2 watt or higher rated resistor.

Using linear regulators will give better regulation and better efficiencies at lower loads.    This is because a zener regulator always draws its design current at a given voltage - either via the zener to ground or into the load.
A linear regulator uses a small amount of current to operate the regulator and then passes only the required current.

Comment: Thank you Soo much and Vin is 9 v

Comment: You can calculate the Rz needed to JUST get the maximum I from my formula above. Be sure to UNDERSTAND how these formulae work. DO NOT just use them without understanding. Note that if the 9V source is a typical small 9V "PP3" battery (Alkaline or zinc chloride or ...) then the voltage will fall to about 6V at its end of life. In that case you need to calculate Iz at end of life as well to see how much regulated current is available in that condition. With output of 3V3 it will be far lower than above and with 4V7 out, even less again. It will

Comment: I am using 9v supply from a full bridge rectifier

Comment: @Kartikey You will want to use a "filter capacitor" after the bridge rectifier. ||Is th=is an assignment / homework or a eal world problem of your own. Assignment questions ARE allowed, but we treat them somewhat differently - more quidance to finding your own answers, so you learn. Either way we provide advice. Or, some of us do .

Comment: It's a real world problem I am making a zener regulated power supply and inhave also used a 1000 microfarad capacitor but accidently used 1k resistor for zener and then the output was not accurate.